# How would I add numbers to a total as check boxes are ticked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you go to the bottom of http://spareslist.com/listing.php?id=56, it will say like "item 1 - 6pts" when you tick the box next to it I want it to add it to the total offered points which is displayed next to "What you will offer". So it will look like "What you will offer - 12pts" if two 6pts items are selected.

Comment: will u please rephrase the question? what do you want to do really?

Comment: well have points counter where you select the items you want and it adds their point value to a total of the offered items and displays it next to the offer title.

Comment: The user will select the items they have and each item will have a point value, each of the items that are selected point values will be added up and displayed.

Comment: Nothing because I don't know where to start.

Comment: You must have written JavaScript before. So create the form, have the buttons, each of the buttons have a VALUE as usual. when you click it, it generates an onClick event. when such an event occurs, call a function which adds up the values. try it and then post if you get stuck.

Comment: ok, thank you, can this be done entirely in javascript (ie. no jquery)?

Comment: @Yesterday, anything you do in jQuery can entirely be done in JS because jQuery _is_ JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to add an element inside the "What will you offer", with an ID so that you can reference it with JQuery.

```
<h3>What you will offer <span id='totalPoints'>0</span> points</h3>
```

Secondly, you need to add the points value to the checkboxes so that there is something to add, and a class so that JQuery can reference them:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="offer-1" value="6" class="offer">
```

Now you can use JQuery to check for the checkboxes being ticked:

```
$('.offer').click(function() {
    var points = $('#totalPoints').html();
    if($(this).checked()) {
        points += $(this).value(); //has been ticked
    } else {
        points -= $(this).value(); //has been un-ticked
    }
    $('#totalPoints').html(points);
});
```

You'll probably need to do a lot more than that, but hopefully that will get you started.